# Unable to send email through localhost after configuring php.ini

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost

Okay, so here's the deal. I followed all the instructions (found in stackoverflow, thanks) to reconfigure the php.ini settings to send emails through localhost using gmail's smtp. I was using the wired connection at my workplace.

All is fine till I used my own wifi connection at home. A simple mail() function took more than 30 seconds to finish executing the code. I have to change the execution time limit at php.ini to 300. Only after I did this, the code managed to finish executing without encountering fatal error. And yet, no emails received. It was working perfectly fine at my workplace. In fact, it executed the code way faster too.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need:

```
WAMP Server
Fake Sendmail for Windows
An email account with any email providers,
Stunnel (if Fake Sendmail itselft doesn't work)
```

- See more at: http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/configure-sendmail-wamp

```
alternate and also easy solution-(hardly will take 5 minute )
go to any free hosting site ..sign up there and host your page there.. i prefer 2freehosting.com
and then simply use php mail() function to send email
```